# File uploading using ASP.NET Core 8.0 works fine on Windows but fails in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu, .net-8.0

I'm using Windows OS and Visual Studio to develop web apps. I use Ubuntu Server 22.04 (LTS) as production OS. I can run my app on Ubuntu 22.04 and it works fine but the part of app which clients can upload their files does not work and causes error 500. Unfortunately, I develop my app on Windows and I cannot debug it. After lots of trials, I found the section causes error 500. The following is the section of code that I use for uploading file:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadNewPmFile(IList<IFormFile> uploadedFile)
{
    .
    .
    .
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    var newFileName = string.Concat(userId, fileExtension);
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Data\Temp", newFileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) //***Error is here***
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As you see, `using` section causes error 500 on Ubuntu but it works fine on WIndows.
I'm using .NET 8.0 runtime on both Windows and Ubuntu.
I searched many questions on this site but I could not find anything related to sole this.
How can I fix this problem?

**Update:**
Note that the published app works fine and without error on Windows but the file uploading section does not work on Ubuntu.

Comment: What exact error do you have ?  An exception must be thrown, and that exception will show you more information on what is going wrong .  Have you tried using forward slashes instead of backslashes in your path ?

Comment: @FrederikGheysels The browser console does not show complete error on Ubuntu. It only says `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Is there the try-catch at the server that would look the complete exception with inner exceptions?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, I have put all my code inside `try-catch`. I have used `StatusCode(500,  ex.Message)` for error reporting.

Comment: I don't think backslash will work in paths in linux. You could also "combine" wwwroot, data, temp not hard code the path separator wwwroot\data\temp in that section of the path.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-8.0).

Comment: 500 is the error reporting that goes to the client. What I mean is logging at the server, exceptions have messages you can log.

Comment: Try `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Data", "Temp", newFileName);` - you'll need to verify if this is the correct path.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Debug .NET Core on Linux using SSH by attaching to a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @user246821 your suggestion solved my problem. Thanks. Please add your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux/Unix use `/` as the directory path character whereas Windows uses `\`. See [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-8.0) for more information.

The code in the OP contains:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Data\Temp", newFileName);
```

One can remove `\` and rewrite the code as:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Data", "Temp", newFileName);
```

This will allow [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-8.0) to use the correct directory separator character for the operating system that the code is running on.

For information on remote debugging, see [Debug .NET Core on Linux using SSH by attaching to a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022).